# "The selected directory is not valid home for Lua SDK"?

Tags: windows, intellij-idea, lua, sdk

I'm new here so I apologize if this question is breaking some rule or something. But this is becoming a problem for me. I downloaded Intellij and downloaded the lua plugin for it. Well, now I'm trying to configure lua sdk but everytime I put in the location for it, it says "The selected directory is not valid home for Lua SDK"

What is the valid home? What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You got any screenshots? Where are you pointing IntelliJ to to find the SDK location?

Comment: D:\GameDev\Lua52 that where the files are located. I even tried moving it to different locations like in C:

Comment: Okay, that's fine. How/Where are you configuring in IntelliJ your Lua Home? Can you add some screenshots of your IntelliJ windows?

Comment: http://imgur.com/a/y9p7K

Comment: Your first image shows that `Lua52` doesn't have a drop-down arrow next o it. Implying that it's empty. Does it actually have Lua binaries in this folder? Also, are you sure you haven't just downloaded the Source code and not the binaries for Lua?

Comment: As @Harmelodic points out, what is contained inside `Lua52` directory?

Comment: That's odd. It does have the binaries in it but its for some reason not detecting it maybe?    http://imgur.com/a/jYl5f  These are the binaries in the folder.

Answer (score 2):

The problem might be that your `lua.exe` file is actually named `luaXX.exe` where XX is the version.
In my case it was `lua53.exe`. I renamed just the `lua53.exe` file to `lua.exe`; I didn't rename the rest.

So at first I had:

```
lua53.dll
lua53.exe
luac53.exe
wlua53.exe
```

After renaming the file I have:

```
lua53.dll
lua.exe
luac53.exe
wlua53.exe
```

With this changed, the Intellij plugin detected the folder as a valid home.